# Manipular string

Tags: php, string

Tenho uma *string* dessa forma:

```
$string = "<div class="legenda">Legenda</div>
    <li><a href="link2">02</a></li>
    <li><a href="link3">03</a></li>
    <li><a href="link4">04</a></li>
    <div class="dublado">Dublado</div>
    <li><a href="link1">01</a></li>
    <li><a href="link2">02</a></li>
    <li><a href="link3">03</a></li>
";
```

Queria uma ajuda para manipular e  ela ser mostrada desse jeito

```
Legenda
1
1
1
Dublado
1
1
1
```

No caso, mostrar somente o que está dentro da `<div class="legenda">` do `<a>` e da outra *div*.

Alguém tem uma solução?

Answer (score 0):

Veja se isto ajuda:

**CSS:**

```
.legenda, li, .dublado {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$string = '<div class="legenda">Legenda</div>
<li><a href="link2">02</a></li>
<li><a href="link3">03</a></li>
<li><a href="link4">04</a></li>
<div class="dublado">Dublado</div>
<li><a href="link1">01</a></li>
<li><a href="link2">02</a></li>
<li><a href="link3">03</a></li>
';
```

Comment: Não funcionou :/ dessa forma iria esconder as div, queria manipular a string para modificar elas